# 2D ising model explains phase transition (Para-ferro) in 3D space How?

Tags: ising-model

2D ising model explains phase transition (Para-ferro). How come a 2-D model explain a system where spins are distributed in all three directions?

Comment: The lattice is 2D. But the spins have 3 (non commuting) components.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Each atom in 3 dimensions will have three components of spin.

Answer (score 2):

2D Ising model is not claimed to be the description of real ferromagnetic systems. It is a toy model, unless nontrivial, that admits an exact solution (for the case of $h = 0$) and has a phase transition.

The more realistic model, describing the real magnetism would be an $\mathcal{O}(3)$ Heisenberg model in 3D. It is also an approximation to a certain extent.

Comment: Let's construct a toy model for superconductivity. I am walking 10 miles and doing 100 pushups in a week. Now there is some coupling variable between the two and I also define all variables needed to explain superconductivity. Everything is happening in 10 spacetime dimensions. Now I say this TOY model explain superconductivity. Can  I publish this?

Comment: @Neerajkumar I didn’t really get the point you were trying to make. But if your “TOY model” is self consistent with rest of physics **and** explains superconductivity **and** makes new testable predictions, go ahead and publish it. It’s usefulness however will be decided by other scientists.